# Android fragment to Activity method calling

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have three files such as

1. activity class
2. db handler class
3. fragment class

From my resource file, on a button click I am calling a method (add). The method is defined in the DB Class. and I am trying to call it from the fragment class related with the res file. But when I do I am getting an error:

> Could not find a method add(View) in the activity class MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btStartCall'

I think I need to initialize the method in activity class to use it. But I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me with a simple example?

Comment: You should add `add(View)` method on your `MainActivity` class.

Comment: It would help if you could supply some [sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I defined the method in the db class and called that method by passing parameters from fragment class file.
public void add(View v){
  //do your job
  }
The same I did in the fragment class.
will it be fine if i copy the same method and the method body to the main activity class?

Answer (score 1):

> But when i do I am getting an error telling "Could not find a method
>   add(View) in the activity class MainActivity for onClick handler on
>   view class android.widget.Button with id 'btStartCall'"

You should add `add(View)` method in your `MainActivity` just like:

```
  public void add(View v){
  //do your job
  }
```